# R: Filtering a data frame by matching partial from a list using "grepl"

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a large data frame (`df`) I want to filter by searching for partial matches between a column (`df$column`) and a list (`aList`).

```
aList <- c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3")
```

The variable in my data frame I use for filtering contains values that might only start with the values in the list. Example: `ID1_23` or `ID2AV`.

I would then like to use `grepl` or similar to search for any value in my data frame column that starts with a value from `aList`. My approach on handling this manner when searching after only single values would be:

```
library(dplyr)
newDf <- df %>% filter(grepl("^ID1", column))
```

My problem then arises on how to do the similair with all values in my list. I have tried the following approach:

```
dummyList <- c()
for (i in 1:length(aList)){
    list1 <- dplyr::filter(grepl(paste("\"^", aList[i], "\""), df$column))
    rbind(list1, dummyList)
}
```

which provide me with the follwing error code:

```
Error in UseMthod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for ´filter_´ applied to an obecjt of class "logical"
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `paste0("^(?:", paste(aList, collapse="|"), ")")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `paste` the values together

```
library(tidyerse)
df %>% 
      filter(grepl(str_c("^(", str_c(aList,  collapse="|"), ")"), column))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you elaborate on how `str_c` is working different from `paste` ?

Comment: @MadeObi Sure 
`paste("val", NA)#
[1] "val NA"; str_c("val", NA)#
[1] NA`